# Como restringir o XSD do Authentication Context do SAML 2.0

Tags: xml, validação, xml-schema, xsd

Estou tentando restringir o `Authentication Context XML Schema Definition` da especificação `SAML 2.0`. O documento XSD está disponível em **[aqui](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-authn-context-types-2.0.xsd)**.

A parte que eu estou tentando restringir é uma relacionada a esta parte do XSD original:

```
<xs:complexType name="PasswordType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="Length" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element ref="Alphabet" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element ref="Generation" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element ref="Extension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="ExternalVerification" type="xs:anyURI" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="RestrictedPassword" type="RestrictedPasswordType"/>

<xs:complexType name="RestrictedPasswordType">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:restriction base="PasswordType">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Length" type="RestrictedLengthType" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element ref="Generation" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element ref="Extension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="ExternalVerification" type="xs:anyURI" use="optional"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Bem, eu não sei como restringir o tipo complexo `RestrictedPassword`. Abaixo está o meu XSD, que tenta restringir o XSD original.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema version="2.0"
       targetNamespace="urn:m:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:K"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns="urn:m:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:K"           
       finalDefault="extension"
       blockDefault="substitution">

<xs:redefine schemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-authn-context-types-2.0.xsd">    

    <xs:complexType name="RestrictedPasswordType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="RestrictedPasswordType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="Length" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element ref="Generation"/>
                    <xs:element ref="Extension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="ExternalVerification" type="xs:anyURI" use="optional"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:redefine>    
</xs:schema>
```

Quando eu tento validar este XSD [nessa ferramenta](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.UwJAzK69h31), ela me retorna um erro, que eu não sei o que nem como arrumar. O erro é o seguinte:

```
-- Not valid. Error - Line 12, 51: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 51; rcase-Recurse.2: There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles. Error - Line 12, 51: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 51; derivation-ok-restriction.5.4.2: Error for type 'RestrictedPasswordType'. The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base. –
```

Comment: Você poderia dar mais detalhes sobre o erro que você mencionou.

Comment: Olá Lucas. Segue o erro mencionado. -- 

Not valid.
Error - Line 12, 51: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 51; rcase-Recurse.2: There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles.
Error - Line 12, 51: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 51; derivation-ok-restriction.5.4.2: Error for type 'RestrictedPasswordType'.  The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todas as instâncias do novo tipo devem também ser válidas para o tipo base. Mas no seu esquema é possível definir um `RestrictedPasswordType` que não tem um atributo `Length` attribute (`minOccurs="0"`), que seria ilegal para o tipo base, que tem `minOccurs="1"`. Tornar um elemento opcional não é uma *restrição*.

Remover `minOccurs='0'` de `Generation` é legal porque ter pelo menos um elemento *é* uma restrição.

Além disso sua restrição referencia o elemento `Length` que não é o mesmo que o elemento  `Length` definido no tipo base. O elemento `Length` é um `LengthType` de acordo com o esquema base, e o elemento `Length` do tipo base é um `RestrictedLengthType` que é uma restrição de `LengthType`.

Acredito que se você mudar a declaração `<xs:element>` da sua redefinição para:

```
<xs:element name="Length" type="RestrictedLengthType" minOccurs="1"/>
```

deve funcionar, a menos que haja outros problemas.

**EDIT**: os outros problemas:

Como um novo elemento `Length` está sendo declarado no bloco `<complexType>`, ele precisa ser declarado como `"qualified"` caso contrário ele não será parte do `targetNamespace` e a restrição irá falhar. Para consertar isto você pode:

- Adicionar um atributo `form="qualified"` ao `<xs:element name="Length" ... />`, ou
- Adicionar um atributo `elementFormDefault="qualified" ao elemento``.

Mais informação aqui:

- Sobre regras para redefinições: [XML Schema Part 1 - 4.2 Layer 2: Schema Documents, Namespaces and Composition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#layer2)
- Sobre qualificação e namespaces: [XML Schema Primer - 3 Advanced Concepts I: Namespaces, Schemas & Qualification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#NS)

Comment: Olá, concordo contigo. Mudei o XSD como sugerido, e agora eu tenho o seguinte erro (que é o mesmo erro de antes): Not valid.
Error - Line 12, 51: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 51; rcase-Recurse.2: There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles.
Error - Line 12, 51: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 51; derivation-ok-restriction.5.4.2: Error for type 'RestrictedPasswordType'.  The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base.

Comment: Estou vendo que o documento original que você lincou não declara um `targetNamespace`. Já no esquema derivado ele é declarado. Um esquema derivado não pode ser de um `targetNamespace` diferente do original. Experimente remover os atributos `xmlns` e `targetNamespace` do seu esquema.

Comment: Funcionou. Tirei o `xmlns` e `targetNamespace` e funcionou. Contudo, há outros documentos similares ao meu, que definem um `xmlns` e `targetNamespace` diferente do original, e estes são válidos. Um exemplo seria esse aqui [http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-authn-context-nomad-telephony-2.0.xsd . Sabe me dizer por quê?

Comment: A restrição quanto ao namespace está na [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#layer2) "3 One of the following must be true:
3.1 SII has a targetNamespace [attribute], and its ·actual value· is identical to the ·actual value· of the targetNamespace [attribute] of SII’ (which must have such an [attribute]).
3.2 Neither SII nor SII’ have a targetNamespace [attribute].
3.3 SII has no targetNamespace [attribute] (but SII’ does)." mas pode haver alguma exceção que eu não esteja a par.

Comment: Ah. Estou vendo um problema aqui. A definição do elemento `Length` precisa ser marcada com o atributo `form="qualified"` ou não irá ser incluído no `targetNamespace`. Deve ser esse o problema. Em vez do atributo no elemento, você pode usar `elementFormDefault="qualified"` em `<xs:schema>` que é melhor. Você pode manter suas declarações de namespace, desde que use `elementFormDefault="qualified"`

Comment: Em ambos os casos funcionou, tanto adicionando `form="qualified"` ao elemento como adicionando `elementFormDefault="qualified"` ao elemento `<schema>`. Mas, deixa eu ver se entendi. Se eu adicionar `form="qualified"` ao elemento, isso quer dizer que esse elemento pertence ao namespace do XSD original, correto?

Comment: Se o elemento raiz do esquema não declarar o atributo `elementFormDefault="qualified"` no esquema, todos os elementos declarados dentro de tipos que não tiverem o atributo `form="qualified"` serão considerados sem namespace (namespace nulo). Isto não se aplica aos tipos nem aos elementos declarados em top-level. Aqui tem mais detalhes: [XML Schema Primer - 3 Advanced Concepts I: Namespaces, Schemas & Qualification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#NS)

Comment: Eu li o documento que você indicou e consegui entender o efeito de configurar o atributo `form` do elemento. Muito obrigado! :)